# Python: case where x==y and x.__eq__y() return different things. Why?

Tags: python, object, inheritance, superclass

I'm taking my first computing science course, and we just learned about class implementation and inheritance.  In particular, we just covered method overriding and how classes we define inherit from the `object` superclass by default.  As one of my examples trying out this particular case of inheritance, I used the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __str__(self):
        return "A"
    # Commenting out these two lines to not override __eq__(), just use the 
    # default from our superclass, object
    #def __eq__(self, other):
        #return self.i == other.i

x = A(2)
y = A(2)

>>>print(x == y)
False
>>>print(x.__eq__(y))
NotImplemented
```

I expected the result from `(x == y)`, because as I understand it the default for `__eq__()` is to check if they're the same objects or not, not worrying about the contents.  Which is `False`, `x` and `y` have the same contents but are different objects.  The second one surprised me though.

So my questions: I thought `(x==y)` and `x.__eq__(y)` were synonymous and made exactly the same call.  Why do these produce differing output?  And why does the second conditional return `NotImplemented`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`NotImplemented` value](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) you're seeing returned from your inherited `__eq__` method is a special builtin value used as a sentinel in Python. It can be returned by `__magic__` methods that implement mathematical or comparison operators to indicate that the class does not support the operator that was attempted (with the provided arguments).

This can be more useful than raising an exception, as it allows Python to fall back to other options to resolve the operator use. For instance, if you do `x + y`, Python will first try to run `x.__add__(y)`. If that returns `NotImplemented`, it will next try the "reverse" version, `y.__radd__(x)`, which may work if `y` is a more sophisticated type than `x` is.

In the case you're asking about, `x == y`, Python first tries `x.__eq__(y)`, then `y.__eq__(x)`, and finally `x is y` (which will always evaluate to a Boolean value). Since `object.__eq__` returns `NotImplemented` in all cases, your class falls back to the identity comparison when you use the real operator, but shows you the `NotImplemented` sentinel when you call `__eq__` directly.

Answer (score 9):

The `==` operator is equivalent to the `eq` function, which will internally call the `__eq__` method of the left operand if it exists to try to determine equality. This is not the *only* thing it will do, and if `__eq__` does not exist, as is the case here, it will do other checks, such as checking whether the two are the same object, or `__cmp__` pre-Python 3.

So in a nutshell, your confusion arises from this assumption, which is incorrect:

> I thought (x==y) and x.__eq__(y) were synonymous and made exactly the same call

In fact, `(x==y)` and `operators.eq(x, y)` are synonymous, and `x.__eq__(y)` is one of the things `eq(x, y)` will try to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented the `__eq__()` function for a class, it gets called when you use `x == y`. Otherwise `x == y` relies on a default comparison logic. `__eq__()` does not get implemented automatically when you define a class.

Comment: Actually (if you're using Python 3, or new-style classes in Python 2) there *is* a default `__eq__` that you get for free - the one you inherit from `object`. With old-style classes, if you don't define `__eq__`, you won't ever get `NotImplemented` from it as in the question - you'll get an AttributeError.